# Why are my Boostrap 4 containers overlapping?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

On smaller widths, my Bootstrap 4 container for an image (JSFiddle line 28) is overlapping my container for navigation (JSFiddle line 16). 
Wondering how I can stop this from happening.

```
<div class="container" style="">
  <hr style="width:80%">
  <nav class="custom-navbar">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/architecture/">Architecture</a>
    <a href="/product/">Product</a>
    <a href="/portraits/">Portraits</a>
    <a href="/wildlife/">Wildlife</a>
    <a href="/about/">About</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img class="" src="https://www.rishulbangar.com/img/baan-thai-cover.jpg">
</div>
```

JSFiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/AakLak/npegafkw/5/

Comment: hm looks fine to me, are you able to send a picture?

Comment: It looks fine to me too

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `custom-navbar` class definition have a fixed height:

```
.custom-navbar {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 60px;
}
```

So when the links have to spread over two lines, an overflows occurs. A solution to this problem will be just removing the fixed height, you can check the fix here:

[JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8qgL9h4/)